# How to Keep the same HTTP request in different pages

Tags: javascript, http, jquery

I have a web application which does downloads of some reports in differents pages in my app, I retrieves the report's data from an external API, I am using AJAX call to get this data. As expected, if the user change the page while the report is being generated the user will not be able to download it, the HTTP request is supposed to be canceled.

There are some solutions in my mind for this problem:

- I can open a popup to request the report and keep it open;
- I can leave the whole app inside an IFRAME and request the report out of the page;
- Or I can change the way how to download the reports doing a queue(Just an idea, does not matter now)...

Is there an alternative way to do that?
Would be possible to keep the HTTP request even when the user change the page?

My scenario is in front-end side(javascript) I don't have access to any back-end. But if there is no way in front-end side, I would like to hear from you any idea.

Comment: No you can't, the connection is lost when redirecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ASP.NET SignalR**

ASP.NET SignalR is a new library for ASP.NET developers that makes it incredibly simple to add real-time web functionality to your applications. What is "real-time web" functionality? It's the ability to have your server-side code push content to the connected clients as it happens, in real-time.

You may have heard of WebSockets, a new HTML5 API that enables bi-directional communication between the browser and server. SignalR will use WebSockets under the covers when it's available, and gracefully fallback to other techniques and technologies when it isn't, while your application code stays the same.

SignalR also provides a very simple, high-level API for doing server to client RPC (call JavaScript functions in your clients' browsers from server-side .NET code) in your ASP.NET application, as well as adding useful hooks for connection management, e.g. connect/disconnect events, grouping connections, authorization.

http://signalr.net/

This was the solution my team found out. It's working fine. Our case is only for ASP.NET. But as the own text says, "You may have heard of WebSockets, a new HTML5 API that enables bi-directional...". So, now we can do that.

Answer (score 0):

use `onbeforeunload` to warn the user that if he navigates away from the page the download will be cancelled